# Как создать и добавить в кортеж int/float?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def min(ls=0.0):#
    for i in c2:#take by 1 element
        a,b=srsumm(i)#summ/count
        c=a/b#average
        ls+=round(c,1)
    print(ls)
    return ls
```

Вообщем нужно чтобы в ls записывались данные как в кортеж [1,2,3], а не 1+2+3=6.
Как сделать из ls кортеж и добавлять в него значения?

Comment: Он все равно говорит TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'list'

Comment: Как я уже сказал, оператор `+=` является синонимом для `extend`, а значит, принимает не число, а список чисел (значений). Используйте метод `append` для добавления одного значения.

Answer (score 3):

Вам нужен список, а не кортеж. Кортеж является неизменяемой структурой данных, поэтому добавление элементов в него возможно только через пересоздание, из-за чего довольно неэффективно (возможно, вы просто неправильно называете список, так как приводите пример с синтаксисом списка, а не кортежа).

Создать пустой список несложно:

```
lst = []
```

Добавление в него элементов осуществляется с помощью методов `append` и `extend` (`extend` можно заменить оператором `+=`, но нужно помнить, что этот метод добавляет список, а не одно значение):

```
lst.append(10)      # [10]
lst.extend([1, 2])  # [10, 1, 2]
lst += [5]          # [10, 1, 2, 5]
```

Comment: Напишите ваши контакты, что бы писать вам на прямую.

Comment: И он говорит, что float не хочет добавлять в список.

Comment: @ALPHA Качественно задавайте вопросы, а если что-то требует длительного обсуждения, используйте местный чат. Тем не менее, создание вопросов предпочтительно, так как информация не будет потеряна.

Answer (score 1):

0) То, что у Вас записано (`[1,2,3]`) не *кортеж (tuple)*, а *список (list)*.

1.1) Преобразование в кортеж:

```
ls = (ls,)
```

1.2) Преобразование в список:

```
ls = [ls]
```

2.1) Добавление элемента к кортежу:

```
ls = ls + (1,)
```

2.2) Добавление элемента к списку:

```
ls.append(1)
```